# profile data type on facebook open graph

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-iphone, facebook-opengraph

I am doing an iphone app and trying to include some facebook OG actions in there..
I have an object named 'user'. I created a custom property for 'user' named 'friend' which is of data type profile.

Now, how do I define that datatype in my cocos 2D app ? 
or should I do it on a php page ?? even to do it on a php page I should send some params to that page right. So, how do I define this profile data type ?

Comment: Just send a valid FB user id for that type.